# How to limit the number of processes being spawned at a time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a VB.NET Windows Forms application where the user is supposed to be able to determine how many processes the application is allowed to launch at a time.

My current method mostly works but I've noticed that occasionally the application goes over the set amount. I use two global variables for this, `_ConcurrentRuns` which is 0 at the start of the application, and `_MaxConcurrentRuns` which is set by the user.

```vb
Private _sync As new Object()

' This is called Synchronously
Private Function RunModel() As Boolean
    If CancelExectuion Then Return CancelCleanup()

    Do While True
        SyncLock _sync
            If _ConcurrentRuns < _MaxConcurrentRuns Then
                Interlocked.Increment(_ConcurrentRuns)
                Exit Do
            End If
        End SyncLock
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Loop

    'This is what will launch an individual process and close it when finished
    ret = RunApplication(arg)
    ' The process has been closed so we decrement the concurrent runs
    Interlocked.Decrement(_ConcurrentRuns)

    Return ret
End Function
```

The goal is to let only one thread exit the while loop at a time, I'm not able to catch it in the debug mode however in the task manager it will occasionally go 1-3 processes over what it's supposed to use. This makes me assume that somehow multiple threads are getting inside the synclock somehow, but I have no clue how that could be happening.

I will be very grateful for any and all help that can be provided, thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: For how long does it go 1-3 processes over what it's supposed to? Could it be that Task Manager is being slow in removing entries from display?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's not over the amount for very long, I had not considered that Task Manager could not be accurately representing the current processes. I might have to look and see if there are better process monitors out there. Thanks!

Comment: You could try [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: @AndrewMorton After further investigation with both that tool, and setting it's priority to high in task manager, it does seem like my solution works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that my solution works for this, I don't want to delete this question because it might be helpful to somebody else in the future.

Answer: Use better process monitoring software / set priority to high in task manager.